# Using reserved word in select field

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

> SELECT left FROM dataset.table;
>
> Error:
>    - Unexpected literal left
>
> SELECT "left" FROM dataset.table;

Problem:
 - Will just return `left` as a value

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh I need to use backticks

```
SELECT `left` FROM dataset.table
```

Comment: Or you can give the table an alias i.e. "as a"  and do `Select a.left`

Answer (score 0):

It is a very interesting case that I also had to face recently but for **Amazon QLDB**, I did not find something so concrete in the documentation about it, however I found a very curious way that I am going to share.

```
select dt['left'] from dataset.table as dt
```

You could do something like that, it is a somewhat strange mix but it finally solved the problem I had, I hope it helps.